# Selected UITableViewCell changes background on Scroll

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, uitableview

I have a UITableView with transparent background color, each of its cells have a custom background view, and gray selection style. The selection works fine, but when i select and drag the tableview up or down, the cell changes its background to transparent instead of the custom one. What shall i look to fix it?

EDIT: Source Code as requested by André Morujão

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    RestaurantInfo *restaurantInfo = [requestBean.restaurantArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView

                             dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];




    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]

                 initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault

                 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    }
    else {
        cell = nil;

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]

                 initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault

                 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    }

    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray];

    UIImageView *bgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100)];
    [bgView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"table_cell_bg.png"]]];
    [cell setBackgroundView:bgView];


    UILabel *restaurantNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 310, 15)];
    [restaurantNameLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16]];
    [restaurantNameLabel setText:restaurantInfo.restaurantName];
    [restaurantNameLabel  setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [restaurantNameLabel  setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    [cell addSubview:restaurantNameLabel];


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Can you paste your tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: ?

Comment: i have edited the question with the method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, these aren't necessarily the cause for your problem, but start by doing these:

- no need for the `else` block (or did you just put it there for debugging purposes?)
- it should be enough to apply the `selectionStyle` and background inside the `if` block (unless you're changing them somewhere else)
- the `restaurantNameLabel` should probably be added to the cell's `contentView` and not directly as a subview
- you're leaking restaurantNameLabel and bgView; add `[bgView release]` and `[restaurantNameLabel release]` after you're done with them

Also, are you using a `UIImageView` for any reason in particular? It'd probably be enough to use a `UIView`, or even just to apply a `backgroundColor`.

Comment: like you said, non of these changes solved the problem, any other clues?

Comment: applying a backgroundcolor to cell with pattern image doesnt help too

Comment: I forgot to mention: don't add the UILabel everytime; add it only in the if block and then retrieve it (using viewWithTag: or something similar) and set only the text outside the if block. Also, can you post screenshots of what it looks like before and after? (+ update your code to the latest version)

Comment: Solved. i changed  

[cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"table_cell_bg.png"]]];  

to  

[cell.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"table_cell_bg.png"]]];
 
and removed the backgroundview thing.

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to award the bounty :)

Comment: oh yes, its your's after 18 hours! :)

Comment: Ops, didn't know that - it's my first bounty :) Cheers